# Certified HP server Intel CPU versions for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, hp, cpu, hardware-certification

The web-page http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201509-19196/ indicates that the HP Proliant DL160 Gen9 server with processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 **v4** @ 1.70GHz has been awarded the status of certified for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. Could the processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 **v3** also work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit? Is the CPU version a strict requirement?